# How can I have my PyPI package run by just importing it, and not importing anything from it?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, pypi

I have created my first PyPI package, but have a problem. I would like the user to be able to import the package, named chess-graph, and then run it straight away.

For example, the user can type in `import chess_graph`. Then, they could run the program straightaway with `chart.graph(<link-to-file>)`.

However, when I try to do run the package this way, I cannot do so. Instead, I have to type in `import chess_graph` (after running `pip install chess-graph`) and then following that type `from chess_graph import chart.`

Is there any way for me to be able to have chart be imported along with chess_graph? This is how my directory looks like:

```
/pypi_chess

    /chess_graph

        __init__.py

        chart.py

        game_parser.py

    LICENSE

    README.md

    setup.py
```

My guess is that I could import the chart in the `__init__.py` file, however that does not work.

My `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from chess_graph import chart

print('test print')
```

When I run `import chess_graph` it prints `test print`, but if I try to straightaway type `chart.graph(file)`, it says `name: chart is not defined.`

I know it is importing it, however, as chart is a big file and it takes a few seconds to import chess_graph.

How can I run the chart file just by importing the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `__init__.py` like that, you can do:

```py
import chess_graph

...

chess_graph.chart.graph(file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping that I could do something more like simply chart.graph() or chess_graph.graph(), to simplify the experience for the user. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No, because you need to bring the `chart` variable into scope somehow, either by importing it (`import chart`) or initializing it (`chart = ...`). Without doing either of those, `chart` does not exist in the current scope.